# Enum annotations in Kotlin

Tags: enums, annotations, gson, kotlin

I have an enumeration that is serialized/deserialized by Gson:

```
enum class PacketType {
    NONE;
    [SerializedName("request")]
    REQUEST;
    [SerializedName("response")]
    RESPONSE;
    [SerializedName("event")]
    EVENT;
}
```

Unfortunately, I noticed that Gson ignores `SerializedName` annotations and uses upper case names for enum values. I decided to find out why serialization doesn't work as intended and found out that Kotlin drops all annotations for enum values. How can I make these annotations appear in generated bytecode?

Comment: See answer below, this was resolved in later versions of Kotlin and is no longer an issue past Milestone 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. Please report to the [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

As a temporary workaround, you can write this class in Java

Answer (score 2):

The issue is now fixed, your code now works fine in Kotlin M9 (0.9.66). If you upgrade to that it'll work as you expect.

e.g.

app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.9.66'
 compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

top-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.9.+'
 }
}
```

I confirmed this by making an enum with no relation between the enum names and SerializedName names, and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use enum as @Query param in Retrofit you can override toString():

```
override fun toString(): String {
    try {
        val annotations = javaClass.getField(name).annotations
        for (annotation in annotations) {
            if (annotation is SerializedName) {
                return annotation.value
            }
        }
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        throw RuntimeException(e)
    }
    return super.toString()
}
```