# How use Kotlin enum with Retrofit?

Tags: android, enums, gson, kotlin, retrofit2

How can I parse JSON to model with enum?

Here is my enum class:

```
enum class VehicleEnumEntity(val value: String) {
   CAR("vehicle"),
   MOTORCYCLE("motorcycle"),
   VAN("van"),
   MOTORHOME("motorhome"),
   OTHER("other")
}
```

and I need to parse `type` into an enum

> "vehicle": {
>             "data": {
>               "type": "vehicle",
>               "id": "F9dubDYLYN"
>             }
>           }

**EDIT**

I have tried standard way, just pass my enum to POJO and it always null

Comment: have you tried somethinig?

Comment: @lelloman yes, I have tried standard way, just pass my enum to POJO and it always null

Comment: maybe it's worth mentioning it in your question

Comment: I think the most relevant part here would be which converter are you using...  GSON or something else?

Comment: @LordRaydenMK yes GSON

Comment: have you tried using @SerializedName annotation? according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423590/enum-annotations-in-kotlin it should work

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
enum class VehicleEnumEntity(val value: String) {
   @SerializedName("vehicle")
   CAR("vehicle"),

   @SerializedName("motorcycle")
   MOTORCYCLE("motorcycle"),

   @SerializedName("van")
   VAN("van"),

   @SerializedName("motorhome")
   MOTORHOME("motorhome"),

   @SerializedName("other")
   OTHER("other")
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851314/1011435)

Comment: that's a GSON solution, change to `@Json(name="foo")` for moshi

Comment: @ravidrinek please ask a new question, and include all relevant details, e.g. json parsing lib etc...

Comment: How can I do it with `Int` instead of `String`?

Comment: @CarlosLeonardoCamiloVargas you change the String to an Int and make sure backend also returns an Int

Answer (score 16):

Another option: use a custom (de)serializer that uses the `value` of the enum, instead of the `name` (default). This means you don't need to annotate every enum value, but instead you can annotate the enum class (or add the adapter to `GsonBuilder`).

```
interface HasValue {
    val value: String
}

@JsonAdapter(EnumByValueAdapter::class)
enum class VehicleEnumEntity(override val value: String): HasValue {
   CAR("vehicle"),
   MOTORCYCLE("motorcycle"),
   VAN("van"),
   MOTORHOME("motorhome"),
   OTHER("other")
}

class EnumByValueAdapter<T> : JsonDeserializer<T>, JsonSerializer<T>
    where T : Enum<T>, T : HasValue {
    private var values: Map<String, T>? = null

    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement, type: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): T? =
        (values ?: @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (type as Class<T>).enumConstants
            .associateBy { it.value }.also { values = it })[json.asString]

    override fun serialize(
        src: T, type: Type, context: JsonSerializationContext
    ): JsonElement = JsonPrimitive(src.value)
}
```

The same adapter class is reusable on other enum classes.

Comment: This works nicely if the enum type is String. Is there a way to create a generic adapter for any type? The most common enum values are strings and integers I think, but it would be nice to have a generic way to serialize any type.

Answer (score 3):

In case the backend service responses integers for example. You can you change the constructor parameter as `Int`.

```
enum class Day(val rawValue: Int) {
    @SerializedName("1")
    SUNDAY(1),
    @SerializedName("2")
    MONDAY(2),
    @SerializedName("3")
    TUESDAY(3),
    @SerializedName("4")
    WEDNESDAY(4),
    @SerializedName("5")
    THURSDAY(5),
    @SerializedName("6")
    FRIDAY(6),
    @SerializedName("7")
    SATURDAY(7),
    @SerializedName("-1")
    UNSUPPORTED(-1);

    companion object {
        fun from(findValue: Int): Day = values().firstOrNull { it.rawValue == findValue } ?: UNSUPPORTED
    }
}
```

Nitpick: The `from` function helps you to find an enum value easily by a given `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `kotlinx.serialization`, then you simply need to mark your enum class as `@Serializable` and use `@SerialName` with it's values:

```
@Serializable
enum class VehicleEnumEntity(val value: String) {
   @SerialName("vehicle")
   CAR("vehicle"),

   @SerialName("motorcycle")
   MOTORCYCLE("motorcycle"),

   @SerialName("van")
   VAN("van"),

   @SerialName("motorhome")
   MOTORHOME("motorhome"),

   @SerialName("other")
   OTHER("other")
}
```